# React-native, Get response from "WebView"

Tags: react-native, webview

I am new in react native,

I have integrated "WebView" for user login in my app so, hear i have need only login response like user is authenticate or not without post any parameters or message, authentication is handle by that particular site so its not in my hand and i can't change any thing so it is possible for app login.

If yes then how can i get response in "onMessage" in my webview?

App Flow:
 - Splash screen
 - Login screen (Webview)
 - If user authenticate then redirect on dashboard

I have used "react-native-webview"
[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you got any solution for the issue?

Comment: I have implemented this tings in different way like, We got every time url once it change from web view component, so after user success fully login, URL will be changed and got some user data.

Comment: Can you share some sample code for it? Thanks @VishalGadhiya